# how can i make a uitableview container to bounce within the view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

ok, so this is pretty simple one, but i hope i could explain this clearly - i have a table view that i would like to inset into a container, and then have the table bounces when it reaches the top / bottom. So far, I was able to put my table in a container, but the container is fixed on the view, while the table inside the container bounces. Again, I am looking for a way to fix the table to the container, while having the container bouncing.

Here is what I was able to do, following the code:

[image]

What I want to accomplish is to have the black box bouncing rather than the table within it.

my ViewDidLoad in the view controller .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//General View Setup
     UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundimage.png"]];
     self.view.backgroundColor = background;


//Table View Data 
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     NSArray *appleComputers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iPhone",@"iPod",@"MacBook",@"MacBook Pro",nil];
     NSDictionary *appleComputersDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:appleComputers forKey:@"Computers"];
     NSArray *otherComputers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"HP", @"Dell", @"Windows", @"Sony", @"Ivory", @"IBM", nil];
     NSDictionary *otherComputersDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:otherComputers forKey:@"Computers"];
     [listOfItems addObject:appleComputersDict];
     [listOfItems addObject:otherComputersDict];
 self.navigationItem.title = @"Computers";

// Create a table
 tblSimpleTable.delegate = self;
 CGRect cgRct = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 300);           
 tblSimpleTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:cgRct style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];  // Initilize the table
     [tblSimpleTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

 tblSimpleTable.sectionHeaderHeight = 30.0;
 tblSimpleTable.sectionFooterHeight = 30.0;
 tblSimpleTable.delegate = self;
 tblSimpleTable.dataSource = self;
 [self.view addSubview:tblSimpleTable]; 



//Create the header 
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)];
UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 40)];
headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Header for the table", @"");
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[containerView addSubview:headerLabel];
 self.tblSimpleTable.tableHeaderView = containerView;



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don’t you use UIScrollView for that.

I had tested your code & done required changes. Hope you like it.

Code :

```
(this is your .h file)

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface tableScrollViewController : UIViewController 
      <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate> {

    UITableView *tblSimpleTable;
    NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
    NSMutableArray *appleComputers,*otherComputers;
        UIScrollView *scrollView;
  }

 @end


 (this is your .m file)


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600)];
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 800);   

 appleComputers = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] init];   // I made it by my style
    [appleComputers addObject: @"iPhone"];
    [appleComputers addObject:@"iPod"];
    [appleComputers addObject:@"MacBook"];
    [appleComputers addObject:@"MacBook Pro"];

    otherComputers = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] init]; 
    [otherComputers addObject: @"HP"];
    [otherComputers addObject:@"Dell"];
    [otherComputers addObject:@"Windows"];
    [otherComputers addObject:@"Sony"];
    [otherComputers addObject:@"Ivory"];
    [otherComputers addObject:@"IBM"];

self.navigationItem.title = @"Computers";

// Create a table
tblSimpleTable.delegate = self;
CGRect cgRct = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 600);           
tblSimpleTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:cgRct 
                                 style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];  // Initilize the table
[tblSimpleTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

tblSimpleTable.sectionHeaderHeight = 30.0;
tblSimpleTable.sectionFooterHeight = 30.0;
tblSimpleTable.scrollEnabled = NO;
tblSimpleTable.delegate = self;
tblSimpleTable.dataSource = self;
[scrollView addSubview:tblSimpleTable]; 

self.view = scrollView;

//Create the header 
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)];
UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 40)];
headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Header for the table", @"");
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[containerView addSubview:headerLabel];
tblSimpleTable.tableHeaderView = containerView;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
return 2;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
if(section == 0)
  return [appleComputers count];
else if(section == 1)
    return [otherComputers count];
}

 // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   
                       cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView 
            dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if(indexPath.section == 0)
        cell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@“, 
                                         [appleComputers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
else if(indexPath.section == 1)
        cell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@“,
                                        [otherComputers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
 }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
             (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
  // do whatever here
 }
```